# Most Frequent Character-Issue - Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to Write a program that lets the user enter a string and displays the string that was entered and the most frequently occurring character in the string. The program can treat upper and lower-case characters the same. If there is tie, then both characters should be output. Use the following strings to test the program:

```
The House on Haunted Hill
Python programming is fun
Gone with the Wind
```

The program works as its intended only on "Python programming is fun", but I only get the frequency of the character on the other 2, but not the letter.

```
def main():

    string = input('Enter a sentence: ')

    string.lower()

    counter = 0
    total_counter = 0

    most_frequent_character = ""

    for ch in string:
        for str in string:
            if str == ch:

                counter += 1
        if counter > total_counter:
            total_counter = counter
            most_frequent_character = ch
        counter = 0

    print("The most frequent character is", most_frequent_character, "and it appears", total_counter, "times.")

main()
```

Comment: This is fine as a coding exercise. For production code, take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: "I only get the frequency of the character on the other 2, but not the letter": what does this mean?

Comment: One obvious problem is that `string.lower()` needs to be `string = string.lower()`.  Without assigning it to something, it has no effect.

Comment: It's also a really bad idea to overload the `str` type by using it as a variable.  You should use a different name.

Comment: Also it looks like you are not stripping the whitespace. So the most common character could be a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these two lines after getting the input from the user.

```
string = string.lower()
string = string.replace(" ", "")
```

You need to lowercase all the characters and then strip the whitespace (assuming you are not counting whitespace as a character).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *are* getting the most frequent character.  YOu left spaces in your input; space will often be the most frequent character.  Note the output:

```
The most frequent character is   and it appears 4 times.
                               ^
```

See the extra space in there?  The middle one is your most frequent character.

Try changing your input conversion line to also remove spaces:

```
string = string.replace(' ', '').lower
```

Now, the output is

```
> Enter a sentence: The House on Haunted Hill
The most frequent character is h and it appears 4 times.
> Enter a sentence: Python programming is fun
The most frequent character is n and it appears 3 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

> If there is tie, then both characters should be output.

If there are multiple letters with the same maximum frequency, then maybe use a list to store those letters.

```
from collections import Counter
s = "Hello SO!"
c = Counter(list(s.replace(' ','').lower()))
max_freq = max(c.values())
letters = [letter for letter in c if c[letter] == max_freq]

msg = 'Most frequent character is {} and it appears {} times.'
print(msg.format(','.join(letters), max_freq))
# Most frequent character is l,o and it appears 2 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alph = [0]*26  
s = input()
s = s.lower()
max_freq = -1
for c in s:
    if c != ' ':
        alph[ord(c)-ord('a')] += 1
        if max_freq < alph[ord(c)-ord('a')]:
            max_freq = alph[ord(c)-ord('a')]
for i in range(26):
    if alph[i] == max_freq:
        print("Character : ",chr(i+ord('a')),", Frequency : ",alph[i])
```

The alph array is initialised to 0 for all characters from a-z.

> ord(c) - ord('a')

calculates which alph index needs to be incremented

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting the letter for the first one is because space is considered as the most frequency character. To get rid of space, you can try my edited here. just add a command line to pass when the space is being counted. and i placed the lower() at the first line to make its works.

```
def main():

    string = input('Enter a sentence: ').lower()

    counter = 0
    total_counter = 0

    most_frequent_character = ""

    for ch in string:
        if ch == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            for str in string:
                if str == ch:
                    counter += 1
            if counter > total_counter:
                total_counter = counter
                most_frequent_character = ch
            counter = 0
    print("The most frequent character is", most_frequent_character, "and it appears", total_counter, "times.")

main()
```

```
output:
Enter a sentence: The House on Haunted Hill
The most frequent character is h and it appears 4 times.
```